# Как задать php скрипту что он Windows-1251?

Tags: php

Задавал в ispamadger кодировку CP1251, но он не хочет обрабатывать кирилицу как строку, echo htmlspecialchars($row['title']) ничего не выводит но если просто его вывести то выводит как дать знать скрипту Php что он работает на win-1251 ?

Comment: мысль прочитать документацию на htmlspecialchars() в голову не приходила?

Comment: @Ипатьев, я ее читал но не суть важна в cms есть функции который чистит от лишних символов строку но в конце строка становится пустой, так как php считает что строка utf8

Comment: надо прочитать еще раз. там все написано

Comment: @Ипатьев, это в cms
```
$title = $row['title'];
//echo $title; ТУТ РАБОТАЕТ
$title = htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $title ), ENT_QUOTES, $config['charset'] );
$title = str_replace("&amp;","&", $title );
//echo $title; ТУТ уже нет
```

Comment: да хоть в курии кардиналов Папы римского. я вот не понимаю - какой смысл сидеть талдычить про свою цмс если ответ все равно будет тот же - пойти прочитать документацию?

Comment: ну вот в $config['charset'] и надо писать что-то осмысленное, а не то что у тебя сейчас

Comment: и убери ради бога stripslashes и str_replace

Comment: @Ипатьев, не я делал это скрипт просто не работает я просто хотел спросить как установить скрипту что он  windows1151, в панели поставил CP1251, но скрипт не хочет работать с кирилицами. Скрипт не мой это cms dle. Изменять что то в скрипте думаю не стоит. Просто нужно найти как установить чтобы он работал со строками из базы win-1151

Comment: ещё раз. при чем здесь "скрипту" если **кодировка  у тебя явно указана** в htmlspecialchars? и что бы ты не устанавливал "скрипту", **подставляться будет та, что написана в $config['charset']**

Comment: @Ипатьев, там указан windows-1251

Comment: не указан. потому что когда указан, то **все выводится** https://phpize.online/?phpses=06ef906c27bb8f040af93f8d5b0bff55&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57